# Ordenar Select2 en orden de selección

Tags: javascript

Tengo un select múltiple con Select2 y necesito pasar los datos de manera en como han sido seleccionados; pero al momento que los paso, me los pasa de la manera en la que están ordenados en el option.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.